# Wired shift caused by when using pd.concat(x,y)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I have a data set x and y. x is a one list that applies to all y data. Using the `pd.concat([pd.Series(x),pd.DataFrame(y)], axis=1)`, I hope to attain the following:

```
x1   y1   ya
x2   y2   yb
x3   y3   yc
x4   y4   yd
x5   y5   ye
x6   y6   yf
```

- x contains x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6.
- y contains [y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6],    [ya,yb,yc,yd,ye,yf].
- x and y are in pandas DataFrame.

Running either `pd.concat([pd.Series(x),pd.DataFrame(y)], axis=1)` or `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x),pd.DataFrame(y)], axis=1)` results in the following

```
x1   Nan   Nan
x2   Nan   Nan
x3   y1   ya
x4   y2   yb
x5   y3   yc
x6   y4   yd
     y5   ye
     y6   yf
```

So the code y values are shifted to the `axis=0` direction by two cells. I have index in this DataFrame. I have removed the index. No difference was observed.

This shift is observed only once I concatenate x and y.

How could I shift the y values upward by two?

Thanks!

Comment: How are x and y defined (can you give the code on how you create them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the indexes of the 2 series are not aligned. Try after resetting the index (`reset_index(drop=True)`)so both series or dataframes have indexes aligned:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(x).reset_index(drop=True),pd.DataFrame(y)
               .reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x).reset_index(drop=True),pd.DataFrame(y)
                              .reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

***Adding an example:***

```
s1=pd.Series([1,2,3]) #normal indexed
s2=pd.Series([4,5,6],index=[2,3,4]) #index starts from 2
```

Normal concat on `axis=1`

```
pd.concat([s1,s2],axis=1)
```

---

```
     0    1
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  4.0
3  NaN  5.0
4  NaN  6.0
```

---

Concat with `reset_index()`

```
pd.concat([s1.reset_index(drop=True),s2.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

---

```
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```